# How to investigate and fix a JVM crash?

Tags: crash, jvm

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f0ac3f0f4e3, pid=3049, tid=139682398594816

JRE version: `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)`
Java VM: `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)`
Problematic frame:

> J 39644 C1
>   org.netbeans.spi.java.hints.ErrorDescriptionFactory.resolveDefaultFixes(Lorg/netbeans/spi/java/hints/HintContext;[Lorg/netbeans/spi/editor/hints/Fix;)Ljava/util/List;
>   (356 bytes) @ 0x00007f0ac3f0f4e3 [0x00007f0ac3f0f2e0+0x203] Failed to
>   write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core
>   dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again If you
>   would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

Comment: What were you trying to do?

Comment: @MarioTrucco I have developed an web application which is continuously running in memory and displaying content like digital signage and while execution of my program jvm suddenly crash and also stops tomcat.